# Ошибка перехода на страницу оплаты Webview Android

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть приложение, которое открывает сайт, где есть возможность пополнения кошелька, при нажатии на кнопку `Оплатить` открывается белый экран и в логах возникает ошибка:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Feature-Policy header:
> Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source:  (0)

Comment: был момент в работе когда из webview требовалась оплата через Tinkoff. Помню были сложности и сделали на этом моменте переход в браузер для оплаты.

Comment: @AVRamones подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: для начала можно показать код с которым у вас возникли трудности